# Не работает background-image. Что не так?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Вот код. **Ссылка правильная**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
 width: 200px;
 background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/gcBRYX0p/unnamed-3.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Оберните путь внутри `url()` в кавычки и добавьте блоку высоту.